# Confusion with how fetch api works

Tags: javascript

I was learning fetch api and am a bit confused with this code:

```
fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json')
  // .then below runs when the remote server responds
  .then(function(response) {
    // response.text() returns a new promise that resolves with the full response text
    // when we finish downloading it
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(text) {
    // ...and here's the content of the remote file
    alert(text); // {"name": "iliakan", isAdmin: true}
  });
```

So, as you can see from the above code, we send Get request to a certain location. Then fetch returns promise with response object containing only headers as response **Without the file itself**. Is that correct? Then to get the file itself as text we make additional request to server. Is that correct? Or if we want to use response.json() then server will send us the parsed JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chaining a promise and making an HTTP request are different things. In the case of fetch, you do indeed chain one promise to another, but doing so doesn't result in another HTTP request to the server. Instead, what happens is that the first promise fulfills after receiving the headers, and then the second fulfills after receiving the body of the same request.

Comment: hey Joseph, thank you for your kind reply. Ok, maybe a weird question, why wasn't it possible to make it one request, that is, get both header and body in one then without chaining them. Would you please tell the reasons of first getting response headers and then body itself instead of getting them both right away as one then().

Comment: You could, alert(response.text()) without chaining. I believe the example is to show that you may continue the chain if you so desire. You may for example want to get log in data from a user with a promise, then log in. then update the page as a chain. Instead of using callbacks across three functions, which don't indicate their relationship instantly when looking at the code.

Comment: @wayne...you can't `alert(response.text()` ... all the content methods return promises

Comment: @charlietfl My bad. I would disagree with the design consideration making content methods returning promises as there is no need. But you could alert(await response.text()).

Comment: @MMMMMM because the metadata should be checked before proceeding with the body since fetch() doesn't treat non 200 responses as rejections. So a 404 will still resolve in initial promise and to properly use the api should check the response metadata before resolving the body

Comment: @Wayne main reason is if there is a parsing error it will get caught in the promise and throw to the catch used in chain

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for your kind comments:), please can you explain "since fetch() doesn't treat non 200 responses as rejections" in a different way. Sorry about that it is so difficult to be beginner :D

Comment: @MMMMMM a 404 means not found...or it could be a 400 Bad request or even a 500 server error. Will only have `response.ok` if it is a 200 status which is a good request. Read up on http status codes and what they mean